# How to pass variables to a function argument using add_action

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, actions, email

I have a test.php plugin file inside my plugin/ folder and I am trying to send an email from this plugin.

I have a code that looks like this currently in my plugin.

```
   add_action('init', 'email_notifier', 10, 5);

   function email_notifier($type, $email, $subject, $body, $link){
    // wp_mail(....)
   }
```

However it seems there is no way to pass outside variables to the `email_notifier` function.

I can send an email like this

```
add_action( 'init', 'email_notifier', 10, 2);
function email_notifier() {
   // wp_mail( 'mail@example.com', 'subject', 'content' );
}
```

But this limits me from dynamically setting and passing the email/subject/content to the function.

Is there any workaround for this

Answer (score 3):

Take a look into this example:

```
add_filter('some_hook', $callback = function( $arg ) use ( $values ){
    //Some calculation here
});
```

You can set arguments this way, and also use the predefined variables that exist outside the functions scope, by using the `use()` term.

This way, you can unhook the function wherever you want, by doing this:

```
remove_filter('some_hook', $callback);
```

Comment: nice touch with the callback variable but IMHO with you going that way it is better to do the dynamic function creation outside of the `add_filter` itself, and obviously make the `$callback` an object property or global. just my 2 cents

Comment: @MarkKaplun Thanks that'll work too. This was actually in one of the answers to my own question, which had 3 methods, including this, yours, and using global variables.

Comment: Thanks for this. I am assuming somehook is `init`?

Comment: @meskerem You are welcome. It can be any action or hook. I just left it that way so you can replace it with whatever you wish.

Comment: This function works if I use on the global scope. If I am using it in a function called ex: `foobar` then the email is not sent. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @meskerem Do you mean if you use the filter inside a function? Have you tried and dumping variables to see if you can get them inside your filter? Try `wp_head` filter and echo your variables, see if they are printed in head.

Comment: At this point I can't tell what I'm doing wrong/right. I've been on this issue for 3 days. I have a file called `templates_ajax_functions` located in  `foo.com\wp-content\plugins\wpjobhunt\templates\dashboards\candidate\templates_ajax_functions.php` and this is what is looks like https://pastebin.com/RUSAuLSs don't mind syntax errors, I just want to know if I am using the filter correctly in a file like that where I can't call `wp_mail` because I get `wp_mail .. Undefined Function` error. It would've been easy if it call wp_mail there, but your suggestion doesn't send email for some reason.

Comment: Are you directly calling that file? You should load WP with `require_once(ABSPATH."/wp-load.php");` if you are trying to directly call the php file (which is not recommended), or you can simply use `mail` instead of `wp_mail`.

Comment: Which file? The `template_ajax_functions.php` comes (i think) with the wpjobhunt plugin. I am executing the function inside that file with ajax using url: `url: "https://foo.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"` the function works but not the add_filter. I am only trying to include wp_mail in that file.  Is there anyway to do this with actions or filters?

Comment: @JackJohansson Sorry to bother you, do you have any idea how I can fix this? I've been on this error for over a week now.

Comment: @meskerem Hi. The native php mail didn't solve your problem? Also there is a link to another question with the exact same problem as yours.